# Android ListView full scroll to the top while using clipToPadding="false"

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I have this litle custom ListView witch is actually a 'ListView' with some call backs. When i dynamically change padding when starting the Activity (Height of the Toolbar), Items dose not respond to padding, and i have to scroll to the top some how.

This is my ListWiew.

```
<somesustom.cutom.ObservableListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:theme="@style/ListView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

So the question is How to scroll fully to the top from code?

**So i have found the solution**

first i deleted `android:clipToPadding="false"` from xml. 
then i configured my `ObservableListView` like this

```
public class ObservableListView extends ListView {


    private boolean clipPadding = true;

    public ObservableListView(Context context) {
        this(context, null, 0);
        setScrollListner();
    }

    public ObservableListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
        setScrollListner();
    }

    public ObservableListView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        setScrollListner();
    }



    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        if(clipPadding)   /// this is the trick, if clip to padding is true, then set selection 0
            setSelection(0);
    }

    public void setScrollListner()
    {
        clipPadding = true;

        super.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {

                if(clipPadding && scrollState == OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_TOUCH_SCROLL) {
                    setClipToPadding(false);
                    clipPadding = false;  // if ii begin to scroll clipPadding 
                    // turns to false and onMeasure set selection not being called.
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            }
        });
    }

}
```

Not sure if this method wouldn't work if i change padding on button click i guess. But in my case, where i set padding from ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener this works quite well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try one of two things or both:

```
listview.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
```

or

```
listview.setSelection(0):
```